# BSON library for java?

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

We have good support for JSON in java http://blog.locut.us/main/2009/10/14/which-is-the-best-java-json-library.html but what about BSON.

What library do you know that provides BSON support for java? 
It should obviously be efficient in runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [BSON site](http://bsonspec.org/#/implementation) is pointing at [this](http://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/com/mongodb/RawDBObject.java)

If you want to use it from MongoDB, take a look at [this example](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/BSON#BSON-Java)

Comment: Guess I could take the encoding part from Mongo and make it an external library. Was hoping from something more "mature", thanks for the tip.

Comment: to be honest the mongoDB example is a bit retarded! why it couldn't be as easy as json conversion?

Comment: The answer has a broken link

Answer (score 7):

You can use the MongoDB driver for Java to store a BSON object, then convert that to a `String` which you can then wrap with [`JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/java/).

For example, here's how I'll create a regular document:

```
BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
obj.put("name", "Matt");
obj.put("date", new Date());
```

Then, to get a `String` representation of the object, simply call:

```
String bsonString = obj.toString();
```

Wrap it with a `JSONObject` and get the date attribute, which should return it in a BSON-compliant format.

```
JSONObject newObject = new JSONObject(bsonString);
System.out.println(newObject.get("date"));
```

The resulting output is something like:

```
{"$date":"2012-08-10T05:22:53.872Z"}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get our Model in MongoDB we used google gson to convert our model into JSON first and then we used the [JSON util parse method from MongoDB](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.1/index.html) to parse our generated JSON string to a DBObject which you can put in your MongoDB. I don't know about performance to be honest.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you are going to lose some data types (such as Date).

Answer (score 1):

There is also a rather new [BSON4Jackson](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/bson4jackson) project, which allows one to use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) for handling BSON data. This means full data binding (to/from POJOs), tree model, even streaming (incremental) reading/writing to degree it can be done with BSON format.

Comment: I hate Jackson. Its API just screams "overcomplication". Crockford's library is the best and the smallest.

Comment: You are entitled to your ill-conceived opinion. Toy libs like org.json's reference implementation are probably a good fit for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [ebson](https://github.com/kohanyirobert/ebson). I've not tried it...