# How can I add an image file into json object?

Tags: android, json

I want to add an image file into json object . Is it possible to add image file into json object?

I tried below code but its not working ? Because i want to send that json object to the server then server will read my image file and store into that database.

```
JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
test.put("photo",new File(// Here i set image uri));
```

So when I print this json object it only show me the image path where the image stored. I want file for sending it to server.

Comment: I don't find it vague... it is just simple. He's just asking how could he add this data to a json object.

Comment: Is that Java you're using?  How would I do this in straight json text?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You will need to read the `bytes` from that `File` into a `byte[]` and put that object into your `JSONObject`.

You should also have a look at the following posts :

- [ByteArray in JSON](http://www.coderanch.com/t/422694/Web-Services/java/ByteArray-JSON)
- [Binary Data in JSON String. Something better than Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64)
- [BSON library for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656335/bson-library-for-java)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

You're only adding the File object to the JSON object. The File object only contains meta information about the file: Path, name and so on.

You must load the image and read the bytes from it. Then put these bytes into the JSON object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . can you give me the simple example of that so i can refer it.

Comment: Did you ever get an example or can you post yours, I am dealing with this issue currently.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class UploadToServer extends Activity {

TextView messageText;
Button uploadButton;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

String upLoadServerUri = null;

/********** File Path *************/
final String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/";
final String uploadFileName = "Quotes.jpg";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);

    uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    messageText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageText);

    messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- '/mnt/sdcard/"
            + uploadFileName + "'");

    /************* Php script path ****************/
    upLoadServerUri = "http://192.1.1.11/hhhh/UploadToServer.php";

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "",
                    "Uploading file...", true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                        }
                    });

                    uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
}

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + uploadFilePath + ""
                + uploadFileName);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                        + uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
            }
        });

        return 0;

    } else {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                    sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            // dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
            // + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: post-data; name=uploadedfile;filename="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8") + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                + " http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                + uploadFileName;

                        messageText.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this,
                                "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }

            // close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText
                            .setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this,
                            "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this,
                            "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                    "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
}
```

> PHP FILE

```
<?php
$target_path  = "./Upload/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
" has been uploaded";
} else{
 echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```