# Accepting json image file in Python

Tags: python, json

How can we accept json image files in python ? we use `josn.loads` for data but what about image files?

Comment: What do you mean by "json image files"? (refer to this thread e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726400/how-can-i-add-an-image-file-into-json-object)

Comment: i meant that i get an image file as json i want to convert this json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is **JavaScript Object Notation**. It is used to convey information with the use of basic types, *strings, integers, floats, booleans etc*.

It can be used to convey meta data about resources, but not typically the resources themselves.

For instance, you might receive a JSON object like the following:

```
a = '''{
  'imageUrl': '/images/image.png',
  'imageName': 'My Image'  
}'''
decoded = json.loads(a)
```

Typically you use this representational information to retrieve the resource on their own. You could do this in python with the standard library's networking modules.

```
import urllib2
img = urllib2.urlopen(decoded.imageUrl).read()
```

Answer (score 9):

JSON is a *textual* format. Since images are opaque binary data, you'd need to encode that data into a textual format.

Base64 is most commonly used for such data, which python can handle just fine with the [`base64` module](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html):

```
import base64
import json

image = base64.decodestring(json.dumps(data)['image'])
```

This is what Twitter supports for [updating your profile image](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/account/update_profile_image).

However, using JSON for image data is *not a good idea* for all but very small images. The json parser included in python will easily overload with a large payload like a decently sized image.

You'd be better off providing a REST API that accepts images using a PUT or POST request instead, then communicate about the image using URLs.