# How to Convert inputStream to JSONObject. Needs to upload File over Android Application

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I have a file ABC(inputstream) that needs to upload from Android App over Jersey Java Rest Server.I am able to send the file alone but I have jsonObj(object converted to json ) along with file.

I am trying to convert inputstream into json String and then insert it into jsonObj. But no luck. Please guide me the way to approach this.

---

**Update [1]**

**Java Client:**

1. ***with JSONObject***

   ```
       ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
       Client client = Client.create(config);
       WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());

       JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
       json.put("id", "1213");
       json.put("name", "3");
       json.put("date", "2013-12-09");
       String input = new String( json.toString());

   ClientResponse response = service.path("/insert/").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                   post(ClientResponse.class,input);
   ```
2. **with inputStream**

   ```
       String fileName="D://workspaces/src/readMe.pdf";
       InputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);

       ClientResponse response = service.path("/uploadFile").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                           .post(ClientResponse.class, fileInStream);
   ```

I hope Server code not required.

Now this work perfectly, But i want them together, i guess input stream can be merged with JSONObject, the question is how ?? some folks says that Jackson, but i need this client code on android application where i can not afford extra libs.

---

Comment: Are you trying to upload or download the file ? Can you please post some code ?

Comment: Have you implement any code for this?? If you have then post it.

Answer (score 0):

why you can not afford extra libs? Jackson is really nice for this, or Gson.

By the way, you can try the following:

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
String result = null;
try {
    InputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);

    // json is UTF-8 by default
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInStream , "UTF-8"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    result = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) { 
    // handling
}
finally {
    try{
       if(inputStream != null){
           inputStream.close();}
    catch(Exception exc){}
}
```

Comment: ok, then look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726400/how-can-i-add-an-image-file-into-json-object