# Image Doesn't Show in my Android ImageView

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I am creating android web application using RESTFul web services.i have declared code to save Image like this

**onCreateMethod()**

```
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hotelLogoImageView);
    iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

**onSave()**

```
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
    logo = bos.toByteArray();
```

then i am using RESTFul webservices.so i converted **logo(byte Array) to String** and passed logo into **NameValuePair** like:

```
private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hotel_logo",String.valueOf(logo)));
```

In my server side code, again i converted my **String value to byteArray** like:

```
byte[] imgLogo = hotelParams.getFirst("hotel_logo").getBytes(
            Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Finally i saved imgLogo value in my phpMyAdmin Database.it's also Stored in Database like `[BLOB - 10 B]`

Now I have to set that image into ImageView.so I have used this method.like

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    byte[] logo = Base64.decode(jsonObject.getString("hotel_logo"),
            Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap hotel_Logo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(logo, 0, logo.length);
    hotelLogo.setImageBitmap(hotel_Logo);
```

After finish this code.there is no error.But Image Doesn't Show in ImageView.please Help me what i have done mistake?

Comment: `String.valueOf(byteArray) == [B@xxxxxxx` not Base64 ... and -1 for asking the same question(yes, with more information, but you could edit the prev one)

Comment: @selvin: i didn't get you.what are you telling?

Comment: just take a look at DB on server side .... your "[BLOB - 10 B]" is nothing but "[B@xxxxxxx" which is not Base64 data

Comment: @Selvin: when i store image,that ll be stored like [Blob-10 B].is it having value?or what?

Comment: @selvin: i am new to webservice and android.so only i dnot have idea on handling image.cant you help me?

Comment: Have you tried just putting the images in res/drawable to make sure your image display code is working?  I would work through it that way one step at a time.  1. images in res/drawable 2. base64 string saved in a raw file or assets or whatever, and decoded into an image 3. hard code base64 string in webservice 4. pull base64 from database

Comment: why you are converting logo to string, you can send it directly as a stream, please search in google how you can do that!! look for an example where image as a stream sends to server

Comment: also look what   nasch  has said in the previous comment, it will help you!!

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay: i am using RestFull webservices.so i need to pass my values as String into List<NameValuePair>.so only i converted my Byte to string

Comment: it is ok i understand than do all what nasch has said before, try with that!! and also look in google that how you can send image to server with restfull web services

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay: no friend i am directly store my image into db.and access from that.so i think that will not be usefull for me

Comment: please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726400/how-can-i-add-an-image-file-into-json-object...it may help you!!

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay :thank you friend.can i have contact with you?

Comment: sure my mail id is given at my stackoverflow profile, however presently at office so not ol