# ImageIo.read method doesn't work in android

Tags: java, android, performance, web-services, iostream

ImageIo.read() doesn't work.the error tells that ImageIo class doesn't contains read method.like

```
    ByteArrayInputStream bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(logo);
    BufferedImage bimage=ImageIO.read(bais);
```

any one help me?

Comment: Any exceptions or messages ?

Comment: @Sanjeev: hmmm yeah i got compile time exception below read() method

Comment: that is because these libraries are not part of android development kit

Comment: answer is updated please have a look

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay: yaa friend i saw.thanks for your answering

Comment: @user3543997 if you want to display image in android you should use BitMap and BitMap Factory classes provided with Android

Comment: its a good question so i raised with +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageIo`  is part of JRE not directly to android, so you may face problem!!

visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html

and we can say that Android is not stand art java - it lacks certain classes. what can be suggested is you can go for similar approaches and try to find out some similar straight solution or  library project which can help you .

Answer (score 1):

Imaging libraries are not a part of Android development kit. if you want to display images in android you should use `BitMap` and `BitMap Factory` classes provided with Android.

Comment: can i use file concept within android?

Comment: What do you mean by file concept ?

Comment: can i use File Io Streams

Comment: @user3543997 can you tell us that what exactly you wants to do? that we can solve the problem and can give an idea to solve.

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay,Sanjeev: i am new to android [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280953/image-doesnt-show-in-my-android-imageview] please visit this link.i have declared my problem.please help me friends