# Can I POST or PUT an image to Django RESTful API using $resource of AngularJs or rather javascript in general?

Tags: json, angularjs, image, rest, base64

I searched a fair bit but am not clear if RESTful APIs even accepts image directly. While one article https://community.oracle.com/community/topliners/code-it/blog/2013/07/22/rest-api--uploading-images suggests that it is possible, I see suggestions on using base64 encoding or BSON from posts like [How can I add an image file into json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726400/how-can-i-add-an-image-file-into-json-object)

Is base64 the best option? (I am sending to a RESTful api built using Django REST framework)