# how can i add images in json/gefx data file and add it in nodes in sigma.js

Tags: javascript, json, customization, data-visualization, sigma.js

I am adding json data in nodes and edges of network graph, i am able to display all the data (like x-coordinate, y-coordinate,color,id,label)in nodes and edges but not able to display url(images).is there any solution to display images from json data in all the nodes.

```
<div id="container">
    <style>
        #graph-container {
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="graph-container"></div>
</div>
```

and my script is

```
<script>
    /**
     * This is a basic example on how to develop a custom node renderer. In
     * this example, the renderer will display an image clipped in a disc,
     * with a border colored according the node's "color" value.
     *
     * If a node as the value "image" to its attribute "type", then it will
     * displayed with the node renderer "sigma.canvas.nodes.image", with the
     * urls being its "urls" value.
     *
     * IMPORTANT: This node renderer just works with the canvas renderer. If
     * you do want to display images with the WebGL renderer, you will have
     * to develop a specific WebGL node renderer.
     */
    sigma.utils.pkg('sigma.canvas.nodes');
    sigma.canvas.nodes.image = (function() {
        var _cache = {},
                _loading = {},
                _callbacks = {};

        // Return the renderer itself:
        var renderer = function(node, context, settings) {
            var args = arguments,
                    prefix = settings('prefix') || '',
                    size = node[prefix + 'size'],
                    color = node.color || settings('defaultNodeColor'),
                    url = node.url;

            if (_cache[url]) {
                context.save();

                // Draw the clipping disc:
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(
                        node[prefix + 'x'],
                        node[prefix + 'y'],
                        node[prefix + 'size'],
                        0,
                        Math.PI * 2,
                        true
                );
                context.closePath();
                context.clip();

                // Draw the image
                context.drawImage(
                        _cache[url],
                        node[prefix + 'x'] - size,
                        node[prefix + 'y'] - size,
                        2 * size,
                        2 * size
                );

                // Quit the "clipping mode":
                context.restore();

                // Draw the border:
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(
                        node[prefix + 'x'],
                        node[prefix + 'y'],
                        node[prefix + 'size'],
                        0,
                        Math.PI * 2,
                        true
                );
                context.lineWidth = size / 5;
                context.strokeStyle = node.color || settings('defaultNodeColor');
                context.stroke();
            } else {
                sigma.canvas.nodes.image.cache(url);
                sigma.canvas.nodes.def.apply(
                        sigma.canvas.nodes,
                        args
                );
            }
        };

        // Let's add a public method to cache images, to make it possible to
        // preload images before the initial rendering:
//        renderer.cache = function(url, callback) {
//            if (callback)
//                _callbacks[url] = callback;
//
//            if (_loading[url])
//                return;
//
//            var img = new Image();
//
//            img.onload = function() {
//                _loading[url] = false;
//                _cache[url] = img;
//
//                if (_callbacks[url]) {
//                    _callbacks[url].call(this, img);
//                    delete _callbacks[url];
//                }
//            };
//
//            _loading[url] = true;
//            img.src = url;
//        };

        return renderer;
    })();

    // Now that's the renderer has been implemented, let's generate a graph
    // to render:
    var i,
            s1,
            img,
//            N = 10,
//            E = 10,
            g1 = {

                nodes: [
                    {
                    "label": "Sciences De La Terre",
                    "x": 112.2230224609375,
                    "y": -2.055976390838623,
                    "id": "n0",
                    "url":'img/img1.png',
                    "color": "rgb(255,204,102)",
                    "size": 8.540210723876953
                } , {
                    "label": "Physique",
                    "x": 1883.59228515625,
                    "y": 24.318912506103516,
                    "id": "n1",
                    "url":'img/img2.png',
                    "color": "rgb(255,255,51)",
                    "size": 4.293514728546143
                }, {
                    "label": "Pays Nordique",
                    "x": -659.119140625,
                    "y": -1094.1265869140625,
                    "id": "n2",
                    "url":'img/img3.png',
                    "color": "rgb(255,51,51)",
                    "size": 4.6399359703063965
                }, {
                    "label": "Pigb",
                    "x": 324.859130859375,
                    "y": -200.34991455078125,
                    "id": "n3",
                    "url":'img/img4.png',
                    "color": "rgb(153,255,255)",
                    "size": 4.39528751373291
                }, {
                    "label": "Poussée D\u0027Archimède,1",
                    "x": 3051.099853515625,
                    "y": 905.1744384765625,
                    "id": "n4",
                    "url":'img/book.jpeg',
                    "attributes": {
                        "nodedef": "n1525"
                    },
                    "color": "rgb(255,255,0)",
                    "size": 4.0340681076049805
                }, {
                    "label": "Pollution Control",
                    "x": -1381.4327392578125,
                    "y": 969.9300537109375,
                    "id": "n5",
                    "url":'img/burger.jpeg',
                    "color": "rgb(102,102,0)",
                    "size": 4.075808525085449
                }, {
                    "label": "Baleine Grise",
                    "x": -176.243896484375,
                    "y": -979.921875,
                    "id": "n6",
                    "url":'img/car.jpeg',
                    "color": "rgb(153,255,0)",
                    "size": 4.206028938293457
                }, {
                    "label": "Arctic Summer",
                    "x": -252.80731201171875,
                    "y": 1699.3084716796875,
                    "id": "n7",
                    "url":'img/house.jpeg',
                    "color": "rgb(0,204,204)",
                    "size": 4.39528751373291
                }, {
                    "label": "Métaux Lourds",
                    "x": 1217.7490234375,
                    "y": -1729.1802978515625,
                    "id": "n8",
                    "url":'img/house1.jpeg',
                    "color": "rgb(102,102,0)",
                    "size": 4.6399359703063965
                }
                    , {
                    "label": "Port En Eau Profonde",
                    "x": 66.55622863769531,
                    "y": -1956.13330078125,
                    "id": "n9",
                    "url":'img/img5.jpeg',
                    "color": "rgb(153,0,0)",
                    "size": 4.0340681076049805
                }, {
                    "label": "Decroissance Soutenable",
                    "x": 425.0431823730469,
                    "y": -1451.91259765625,
                    "id": "n10",
                    "url":'img/cube.jpeg',
                    "color": "rgb(255,51,51)",
                    "size": 4.206028938293457
                }, {
                    "label": "Glacier Rocheux",
                    "x": 714.1744384765625,
                    "y": -146.1813201904297,
                    "id": "n11",
                    "url":'img/ball.jpeg',
                    "color": "rgb(153,255,255)",
                    "size": 4.133297443389893
                },
                    {
                    "label": "Fleuve Amour",
                    "x": -529.2616577148438,
                    "y": -1068.8953857421875,
                    "id": "n12",
                    "url":'img/telephone.jpeg',
                    "color": "rgb(102,0,102)",
                    "size": 4.0086140632629395
                }, {
                    "label": "Weather Satellite",
                    "x": 353.239501953125,
                    "y": 2159.915283203125,
                    "id": "n13",
                    "url":'img/cherry.jpeg',
                    "color": "rgb(255,153,153)",
                    "size": 4.936610698699951
                }
                ],

                edges: [
                    {
                        "source": "n0",
                        "target": "n1",
                        "id": "e1",
                        "label":"label-1"


                    }, {
                        "source": "n0",
                        "target": "n2",
                        "id": "e2",
                        "label":"label-2"
                    }, {
                        "source": "n0",
                        "target": "n3",
                        "id": "e3",
                        "label":"label-3"
                    }, {
                        "source": "n0",
                        "target": "n4",
                        "id": "e4",
                        "label":"label-4"

                    }, {
                        "source": "n0",
                        "target": "n5",
                        "id": "e5",
                        "label":"label-5"
                    }, {
                        "source": "n0",
                        "target": "n6",
                        "id": "e6",
                        "label":"label-6"
                    }, {
                        "source": "n0",
                        "target": "n7",
                        "id": "e7",
                        "label":"label-7"
                    }, {
                        "source": "n0",
                        "target": "n8",
                        "id": "e8",
                        "label":"label-8"
                    }, {
                        "source": "n0",
                        "target": "n9",
                        "id": "e9",
                        "label":"label-9"
                    },    {
                        "source": "n0",
                        "target": "n10",
                        "id": "e10",
                        "label":"label-10"
                    }
                    , {
                        "source": "n0",
                        "target": "n11",
                        "id": "e11",
                        "label":"label-11"
                    }, {
                        "source": "n0",
                        "target": "n12",
                        "id": "e12",
                        "label":"label-12"
                    },
                    {
                        "source": "n0",
                        "target": "n13",
                        "id": "e13",
                        "label":"label-13"
                    }, {
                        "source": "n0",
                        "target": "n13",
                        "id": "e14",
                        "label":"label-14"
                    } ]
            },
            loaded = 0 ;

    function getImages(input, field){
        var images = [];
        for(var i=0; i<input.length ; i ++)
            images.push(input[i][field]);
        return images;
    }
    var urls = getImages(g1.nodes, "url");
    // Generate a random graph, with ~30% nodes having the type "image":
    for (i = 0; i < g1.nodes; i++) {
        img = Math.random() >= 0;
        g1.nodes.push({
            id: g1.nodes[i].id,
            type:  'image' ,
            url:  g1.nodes[i].url,
            x: g1.nodes[i].x,
            y: g1.nodes[i].y,
            size: g1.nodes[i].size,
            color: g1.nodes[i].color

        });
    }
    console.log("x coord *****" + g1.nodes[i].x);
console.log("image urls"+ g1.nodes[i].url);
    for (i = 0; i < g1.edges; i++)
        g1.edges.push({
            id: 'e' + i,
//            source: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
            source:g1.edges[i].source,
            target: g1.edges[i].target,
        });

    // Then, wait for all images to be loaded before instanciating sigma:

    console.log("result" + urls);
    urls.forEach(function(url) {
        console.log("url image"+ url);
            sigma.canvas.nodes.image.cache( url, function () {
//                console.log("all images"+urls);
                        if (++loaded === urls.length)
                        // Instantiate sigma:
//                        console.log("hello");
                            s1 = new sigma({
                                graph: g1,
                                renderer: {
                                    // IMPORTANT:
                                    // This works only with the canvas renderer, so the
                                    // renderer type set as "canvas" is necessary here.
                                    container: document.getElementById('graph-container'),
                                    type: 'canvas'
                                },
                                settings: {
                                    minNodeSize: 16,
                                    maxNodeSize: 16,

                                }
                            });


                    }
            );
//        }

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the image to `byte` form, then encode it in `base64` and add the encoded data to the `json` object.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8727522/5929221) for detailed explaination.