# Binary data in cursor android

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am saving a bitmap value in `SQLite` by encoding it into `base64`. I need to create a `JSON array` for all my SQLite values. I am using a a cursor to get all my values from SQLite.

> But the cursor does not hold the whole base64 value, only half base64
>   bits.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: P.S. Ensure that the column of SQLite in which you are storing `base64` encoded string has at least `length` greater than or equal to encoded string length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its not the best practice to save `base64` representation in db:

Please remember `base64` encoding makes file sizes roughly 33% larger than their original binary representations, So you can convert image to `byte[]` and then save it in `blob` field

To save binary data in `JSON Object`, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726400/how-can-i-add-an-image-file-into-json-object)