# How to parse an image from JSON in Phalcon

Tags: php, rest, phalcon

I have an api that transfers data to my mobile app. On the server I'm using Phalcon framework. 
Do you know how can I send photos from my mobile app, to the server, parse them, save them into a folder and then send the response back with the url? I haven't found anything in the documentation

I am using REST with JSON.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these resources:

[ByteArray - JSON](http://www.coderanch.com/t/422694/Web-Services/java/ByteArray-JSON)

[Binary Data in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64)

[BSON Library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656335/bson-library-for-java)